# Smallest square containing a given triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, rectangles

Given a triangle $T$, how can I calculate the smallest square that contains $T$?

Using GeoGebra, I [implemented](http://www.geogebratube.org/student/m119108) a heuristic that seems to work well in practice. The problem is, I have no proof that it is always correct. Here is the heuristic:

1. Try to construct a square whose diagonal is the longest side of $T$. This works if both angles near the longest side are at most 45 degrees (it is shown in green in the demo above).
2. Otherwise, try to construct a square whose side contains the shortest side of $T$. The side length will be the maximum between the shortest side of $T$ and the height to the shortest side of $T$ (it is shown in blue or cyan in the demo above).

Is this heuristic always correct? If not, what is a correct method for calculating the smallest containing square?

Comment: What about trying to solve it using algebraic geometry and calculus?

Comment: @user132181 Can you give an example?

Comment: I was just  trying to sound smart :( ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was thinking along similar lines to those of TonyK, but still different. Let some triangle be given. Let $a$ denote the length of the longest side and $b$ the length of the second longest. Let the angle between those to sides be denoted $\theta$. For $b$ to be longer than the third side we must have $b\cdot\cos\theta\geq a/2$. Then we represent the triangle by the vectors (see [Dynamic GeoGebra Applet](http://www.geogebratube.org/student/m119921))
$$
\vec u=a\cdot\vec e_{t}\qquad\text{and}\qquad\vec v=b\cdot\vec e_{t+\theta}
$$
where $\vec e_s=\begin{pmatrix}\cos s \\ \sin s\end{pmatrix}$ has been defined as the unit vector pointing in the direction of the angle $s$.

Now we start rotating the triangle by changing the value of $t$. For each value of the rotation angle $t$ we form the minimal square with sides parallel to the axes that contains the triangle/the vectors. The size of the minimal squares will be periodic with period $\pi/2$. Thus we only need to consider rotations $t\in[0,\pi/2]$.

To determine the side of the minimal square for a given $t$ let us consider the four functions
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta x_1(t)&=a\cdot\cos t \\
\Delta x_2(t)&=a\cdot\cos(t)-b\cdot\cos(t+\theta) \\
\Delta y_1(t)&=a\cdot\sin t \\
\Delta y_2(t)&=b\cdot\sin(t+\theta)
\end{align}
$$
All of the above are either $x$- og $y$-differences found in the triangle for the current value of $t$. If $\square(t)$ denotes the side length of the minimal axes-parallel square containing the triangle for the current $t$ we then have
$$
\square(t)=\max\{\Delta x_1(t),\Delta x_2(t),\Delta y_1(t),\Delta y_2(t)\}
$$
and the optimal (minimal) value of $\square(t)$ corresponds to one of the intersection points of at least two of the four difference functions. So it is all about solving each of the equations
$$
\begin{align}
\Delta x_1(t)&=\Delta x_2(t)\\
\Delta x_1(t)&=\Delta y_1(t)\\
\Delta x_1(t)&=\Delta y_2(t)\\
\Delta x_2(t)&=\Delta y_1(t)\\
\Delta x_2(t)&=\Delta y_2(t)\leftarrow\text{The equation suggested by TonyK}\\
\Delta y_1(t)&=\Delta y_2(t)
\end{align}
$$
For each triangle this gives (at most) six $t$ values in the interval $[0,\pi/2]$ of which one will be the optimal one.

The only general statements I have found from drawing these situations and plotting the four functions so far, is that $\Delta x_1=\Delta x_2$ can be left out and at least one vertex of the triangle will be placed in a vertex of the optimal containing square.

Also I have found that there are **far more complex situations** than those both the OP and TonyK have come up with.

Comment: This looks good to me

Comment: There are really just two non-trivial cases here. (The second and fifth cases are taken care of by the OP's heuristic 1, which is easy to check.) The last case is the same as the first case, rotated by $90^{\circ}$. And the fourth case is the same as the third case, rotated by $90^{\circ}$.

Comment: What does the last sentence of the answer mean?

Comment: Playing with your amazing GeoGebra applet, it looks like there are 4 cases, for a triangle ABC with a<b<c. (1) If B<π/4, use c as the diagonal of the square. (2) Else if A<π/4, put A in one corner and B,C on the far sides. (3) Else if a<(altitude from A to a), put a on a side of the square, and A on the far side. (4) Else, put C in one corner and A,B on the far sides.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated to add:** It seems that this is wrong. String's answer tells you why.

If two angles are $\le 45^\circ$, then use your heuristic 1. Otherwise, put the smallest angle (call it $\varphi$) at the origin $O$, with side $OX$ of length $a$ along the positive $x$-axis and the other side $OY$, of length $b$, in the first quadrant.

Now rotate the triangle anticlockwise by an angle $\theta$, until the $x$-coordinate of $X$ equals the $y$-coordinate of $Y$. When this happens, all three points lie on a square, two of whose sides lie along the coordinate axes. I think (but haven't proven) that this square is minimal.

The $x$-coordinate of $X$ is $a \cos \theta$, and the $y$-coordinate of Y is $b \sin(\theta+\varphi)$. Putting these equal gives

$$a \cos \theta = b (\sin \theta \cos \varphi + \cos \theta \sin \varphi)$$

or

$$\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac{a - b\sin\varphi}{b\cos\varphi}$$

Comment: I don't think this works. Counterexample: an isosceles triangle with base and height equal to 1. This can easily be fit into a square of side length 1, but your construction results in a side length of about 1.06.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not always correct. One example that fails is a tall, narrow isosceles triangle (for example, side lengths 1, 10, 10). Positioning the triangle diagonally in the square is much better than positioning it vertically.

Comment: You are right, step 2 is incorrect. How can I fix it?