# How to approach this minmax problem (nonconvex)

Tags: optimization

This is my first time to solve the minmax problem, I also read the following discussion:

[How to approach a minmax problem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955109/how-to-approach-a-minmax-problem)

My problem is

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
& {\underset{w_i,\ \ \ \ \  x_i}{\max\min}}
& & w_1(x_2-x_1)^2+w_2(x_3-x_2)^2 \\
& \text{s.t.} & & w_1+w_2=1 \\
& & & x_1+x_2+x_3 = 0\\
& & & x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^3 = 1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Assume I know how to solve the problem if $w_i$ for all $i$ are given. 
Then is there any suggested methods to solve this problem based on this assumption.

Comment: What sort of guarantees are you looking at? Convergence to globally optimal solutions? Convergence to stationary points?

Comment: Convergence to globally optimal solution. This problem admits a globally optimal solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach for solving the saddle point problem $$\underset{w \in W}{\max} \: \underset{x \in X}{\min} \: f(w,x)$$ to global optimality is to reformulate it as the semi-infinite program

\begin{align}
\underset{w \in W, \: z \in \mathbb{R}}{\max} \:\: & z \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & z \leq f(w,x), \quad \forall x \in X.
\end{align}

Since your problem is affine in the space $(w,z)$, there are several cutting plane algorithms for solving this problem assuming that, for a given $(\bar{w},\bar{z}) \in W \times \mathbb{R}$, you can solve the subproblem $\underset{x \in X}{\max} \left\lbrace \bar{z} - f(\bar{w},x) \right\rbrace$ to global optimality. One summary reference is [here](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/prac_robust.pdf).

Comment: How did you say that my problem is affine in the space $(w,z)$?  Thanks!

Comment: Well, I meant the function $z - f(w,x)$ is affine in the variables $w$ and $z$ for each fixed $x \in X$ plus $W \times \mathbb{R}$ is a polyhedral set