# Examples of useful, insightful, and interesting hand-waving

Tags: soft-question, physics, education, big-list

It seems to me that some hand-waving (by which I mean some arguments that aim at giving some form of intuition on the problem even at expenses of *complete* rigour [**and not** mnemonics for high-schoolers or totally bogus oversimplistic smoke curtains]) may be really useful at times to get some insight on a problem.

For example, in Levi's *Mathematical Mechanic* there are many intelligent examples of problems where some physical intuition (while not perfectly rigorous) may help yield some result and even converted into a formal argument.

So, I would like to collect a "big list" of "useful" (and possibly somewhat sophisticated), insightful and interesting heuristics and hand-waving arguments (which may also include some reference to physical principles e.g. see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38909/how-can-simple-physical-proofs-of-mathematical-facts-be-made-rigorous))

Comment: Does "handwawing" mean hand-waving, hand-drawing, or handwriting?

Comment: Hard to answer. I feel like most heuristics go along the lines of "this A looks like B, and for B we know that P(B), so probably P(A)". Now the examples which I'd be brave enough to post are ones which can be formalized anyway. If I write down a heuristic with a wrong conclusion, people will not like it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers by Christian Blatter often contain *A little bit of Physics*.
This one is a wonderful example:

- [How find this inequality $\max{\left(\min{\left(|a-b|,|b-c|,|c-d|,|d-e|,|e-a|\right)}\right)}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611302/how-find-this-inequality-max-left-min-lefta-b-b-c-c-d-d-e-e-a-ri/618630#618630)

A parabola is the trajectory $\,\vec{r}\,$ of a particle with initial position
$\vec{s}$ , initial velocity $\,\vec{v}\,$ and constant acceleration $\,\vec{a}$ .
This leads to the representation
$\,\vec{r}(t) = \vec{s} + \vec{v}\, t + \vec{a}\, t^2$ , as has been employed in:

- [Proving that for each two parabolas, there exists a transformation taking one to the other](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667467/proving-that-for-each-two-parabolas-there-exists-a-transformation-taking-one-to/668644#668644)
- [What is wrong with this method for a rotated and shifted parabola?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711004/what-is-wrong-with-this-method-for-a-rotated-and-shifted-parabola/717255#717255)

The following answer is inspired by the physical - what is "slimness" - and the physics / mechanics of solid bodies
- [Moments of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_ellipsoid) .
With respect to the latter, any - "slim" or "fat" - 2-D body can be thought as an ellipse (of inertia). Then there is a wonderful relationship between the physical, the physics, and the mathematics of 
[Steiner ellipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_ellipse)s :

- [How fat is a triangle?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851185/how-fat-is-a-triangle/917363#917363)

Couldn't really distinguish between physics intuition and a mathematical argument at this place:

- [Proof of the extrinsic to intrinsic rotation transform](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1137745/proof-of-the-extrinsic-to-intrinsic-rotation-transform/1155951#1155951)

Comment: $+1$ Thank you. *This* is the kind of things I was looking for.      
I would really appreciate if you (or Prof. Blatter himself) could compile a collection of such answers. :)

Comment: @Dal: I would be glad to do it, but it's Xmas time and I shall be with my family soon. I'd suggest to check the Answers given by Dr. Blatter and myself (you can find them in our profiles) and I'm sure you will find some. A little bit of Physics in Mathematics is my personal bias.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look. Do you happen to have written some mathematical papers in which you use physical arguments?

Comment: @Dal: Could not find explicit examples of the kind. Rather the other way around: physics papers in which mathematical arguments are employed, as is commonly the case.

Comment: @Dal: Think I've found some more. See my update of the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you find something else, please, don't hesitate to add.

Comment: @Dal: Didn't hesitate to add another update.

Comment: @Dal: added another update. Hope it's relevant.

Answer (score -3):

I use the following in my calculus class to find limits of various quotients when the variable approach zero. They are:

$\begin{eqnarray}(BIG + small)^r &=& BIG^r + r\ BIG^{r-1} small + \cdots\\
\sin(small) &=& small + \cdots\\
\cos(small) &=& 1 - {1 \over 2}small^2 + \cdots\\
\tan(small) &=& small + \cdots\\
e^{small} &=& 1 + small + \cdots\\
\ln(1+small) = &=& small + \cdots
\end{eqnarray}$

Comment: Sorry, but a semi-rigorous version of asymptotic expansions is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Dal,  that is alright. you asked for handwaving that is useful and i gave you one.

Comment: How is this not rigorous?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo, it is rigouros. but, sometimes i feel the reasoning to be circular. kind of using taylor series to find the limits while you are supposed to do limits first. my students like and they can compute complex limits with ease. so i will continue teach this.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo What I meant is that these are only "expansions" with "small" instead of x for x ->0, which could be useful only as *mnemonics*.