# Triangle inside a unit square.

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Consider a square of size 1 and a triangle of sides $a$, $b$ and $c$.

Is there a way to know if the triangle can fit inside the square?

Clearly, if $a>\sqrt{2}$ or $b>\sqrt{2}$ or $c>\sqrt{2}$, it is not possible, but a triangle of sides $\frac{7}{5}$, $\frac{7}{5}$ and $\frac{1}{4}$ does not fit.

My first idea was to rotate the triangle and see if the maximum distance between points in each axis is less than 1...

Comment: Don't you mean $a> \sqrt{2}$?

Comment: The biggest triangle that fits inside a 1-sided square has an area 1/2. Anything with a bigger area cannot. There may be other necessary conditions for lower area triangles.

Comment: This is essentially the same as asking, What is the [smallest square containing a given triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/802612/398708)?

Comment: [Here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3620836#:~:text=Notice%20that%20T%20and%20Q0%20have%20the%20same,square%20that%20contains%20T%2C%20which%20implies%20the%20conclusion.) is an article about this question.

Comment: It seems to me that this is tantamount to requiring that the circumcircle radius, $r\le\sqrt{2}/2$, For the equations of the circumcenter, see, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcircle.

Comment: You don't like any of the answers?

Answer (score 4):

I attacked this question from various angles, with little success at first. Treating it as linear programming minimization problem turned out to be hideously complicated and maybe impossible. In the end the solution turned out to be relatively trivial.

[image]

Use this equation (that was obtained by trigonometry and [the law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines))

$x = c\cdot \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos \left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2 a c} \right) - \arccos \left(\frac 1 a \right)\right)$

where a is the length of the longest side of a triangle with area $\leq 1/2$ and b is the length of the shortest side of the triangle.

If $x\leq 1$ the given triangle will fit.

For an arbitrary square with side lengths (s), replace $\frac 1 a$ with $\frac s a$ and use:

$y = c \cdot \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos \left(\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2 a c} \right) - \arccos \left(\frac s a \right)\right)$

and the triangle will fit if $y \leq s$

Comment: Gracias. What are $x$ and $y$ exactly? I mean what properties of a triangle are we evaluating?

Comment: For a triangle of area less than or equal to $1/2 $, x is the shortest possible length of a side that is orthogonal to a side of unit length of an enclosing rectangle.

Comment: Way to go! Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is essentially a question of showing that the radius of the circumcircle is less than $\sqrt{2}/2$ because the largest triangle that can fit in the unit square is the right-triangle with unit sides, hypotenuse of $\sqrt{2}$ and circumradius of $\sqrt{2}/2$. Let's demonstrate how easy it is to calculate this in the complex plane. Given three random points, say $z_{1,2,3}$, we can determine the circumcenter, $z_c$ and radius, $r$ as shown  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/481357/finding-center-and-radius-of-circumcircle/2058832#2058832).

$$
z_c\
\;=\;\frac{\left|
        \begin{array}{ccc}
          z_1 & |z_1|^2 & 1 \\
          z_2 & |z_2|^2 & 1 \\
          z_3 & |z_3|^2 & 1
        \end{array}
      \right|}
     {\left|
        \begin{array}{ccc}
          z_1\  & {z_1}^*\ & 1 \\
          z_2\  & {z_2}^*\ & 1 \\
          z_3\  & {z_3}^*\ & 1
        \end{array}
      \right|}
$$

and

$$
r=|z_c-z_1|=|z_c-z_2|=|z_c-z_3|
$$

These calculations can probably be calculated by hand, but most likely will be done on a computer. I did just that in a matter of just six lines of code (in Matlab). You can then go on to plot the triangle, circumcircle, and overlay a unit square (though it may not be in the correct orientation).

Answer (score 0):

For a $\triangle ABC$, suppose the longest side = $AB$. Then

1. $AB > \sqrt 2$. $\triangle ABC$ will *not* fit.
2. $AB = \sqrt 2$. $\triangle ABC$ will fit IFF $\angle ABC = 45$ degrees $\vee$ $\angle BAC = 45$ degrees.
3. $AB < \sqrt 2$. It seems necessary to set down some conditions for $1 < AB < \sqrt 2$ especially so if $AB \to \sqrt 2$