# Which square is bigger?

Tags: geometry

Acute triangle $ABC$ has side length $a \ge b \ge c$. We drop the altitude from point $C$ to side $c$, and let its length be h. We construct a square with side length $h$ so that side $c$, points $A$ and $C$ lie on the square's sides and point $B$ lies on its vertex. Then, we construct another square with side $s$ so that $C$ lies on its vertex and points $A$ and $B$ lie on its sides. Which square is bigger?
[image]

I found the equations
$c^2=a^2+b^2-2s\sqrt{a^2-s^2}-2s\sqrt{b^2-s^2}$
and
$4c^2h^2=a^4-2a^2b^2-2a^2c^2+b^4+6b^2c^2+c^4$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/802612/smallest-square-containing-a-given-triangle

Comment: what is $s$? The semi-perimeter?

Comment: the side length of the square that has vertex C

Comment: Seems like $h>s$

Answer (score 2):

This problem is underconstrained. In the square with side $s$ let any qualifying triangle be constructed. Then $h=s$ iff the foot of the altitude to $C$ is on the quarter circle with radius $s$ centered on $C$. And we can clearly construct triangles with feet inside, on, or outside that arc. Your example is outside.

**Edit**: added picture illustrating 3 possibilities, right panel is equilateral.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning. $s$ is unique, are you trying to claim otherwise?

Comment: The problem is simpler in reverse. Fix the second square first, in it construct this or any other acute triangle with vertex $C$ and the other vertices on top and left side. Then $h$ is in the square yet it may be greater than, equal to, or less than the side $s$. Consider the isosceles constructs with a near $90$ apex angle $C$ or near $0$ angle for $h$ less than and greater than $s$, respectively.

Comment: Your construction is vague, but from what I understand, you haven't used $a \ge b \ge c$.

Comment: I’m not seeing the problem or the vagueness, I said let it be any qualifying triangle per the initial description. And the ones I just described qualify.

Comment: Can you add a diagram with $h<s$?

Comment: @DS picture added. In my pre-coffee fuddle this am I mentioned a near-right isosceles in my comment response, that's not qualifying, I forgot the constraints overnight, the equilateral above is the case I should have said there.

Comment: Thanks, it is clear now

Comment: would there be any restrictions on $a$, $b$ and $c$ that would classify any triangle in each of the three categories?

Comment: You could definitely generate the function but you’d need to parameterize the situation. I would slide A along the top from left to right, which restrains B to values yielding longer sides than A yet not more than 90 degrees, and calculate where on that interval you have tangency. The solution is a surface over the 2 parameters. Left as an exercise for the reader 

Answer (score 1):

In the attached figure, your second triangle is red color and your first one is the same black color. You have $$\begin{cases}a\cos(t)=s\\a\cos(u)=h\end{cases}\Rightarrow \frac{s}{h}=\frac{\cos(t)}{\cos(u)}$$ Since $\triangle{ABC}$ is acute we have three possibilities
$$ s\lt h\iff \cos(t)\lt\cos(u)\iff t\gt u\\s\gt h\iff \cos(t)\gt\cos(u)\iff t\lt u\\s=h\iff t=u$$ Obviously these possibilities mean respectively black is bigger,red is bigger and both are equal.

In the figure there are particular values to verify the size of concerned squares with  $(a,b,c)=(10,8,7)$ and the literal calculation is similar but more difficult to manipulate.

We have  $h\approx7.946$; the value of $s$ is not hard to determine; we have the system of three unknowns in which we eliminate $y$ and $z$ $$ y^2+z^2=7^2\\s^2+(s-z)^2=8^2\\s^2+(s-y)^2=10^2$$ We get $s\approx7.91643$ and $s\approx 3.4658$ so **the black square is bigger**.

Note the values of $h$ and $s$ are near. There are positions  for $s\lt h$ and $s\gt h$  for which it is impossible the construction of squares such as asked but I not explain about it.

[image]